# Change values of array using state React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Today i tried to change values inside a array using state. So i have a simple array like -

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    {
      label: "data 1",
    },
    {
      label: "data 2",
    },
  ]);
```

Also i dont know is it good idea to use array in state. I created a button and text component also.

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", top: 50 }}>
  <Button
    title={"test"}
    onPress={() => {
      data[0].label = "fdsfsd";
      setData(data);
    }}
  />
  <Text>{data[0].label}</Text>
</View>
```

So my idea is when i click button to change `data[0].label`. But unfortunately it is not change? Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `onPress` to this

```js
onPress={() => {
  let temp = [...data];
  temp[0].label = 'asdasdasdasd';
  setData(temp);
}}
```

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/array-update-state)

Read More about State Updates, Immutable Approaches etc here - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will work

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", top: 50 }}>
  <Button
    title={"test"}
    onPress={() => {
      data[0].label = "fdsfsd";
    }}
  />
  <Text>{data[0].label}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Not working.\1!

Comment: You should not directly mutate your state.